# Each node holds 50% of data on 2 nodes with replication_factor=1

Tags: cassandra

**Description**: Linux OS, Cassandra 3.9, Using [CCM](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm) to create **2 Nodes**, **Consistent Level = One**

```
replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}
```

Using writing script (* ) as below ([Cassandra-Python-Driver](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html)) to `insert` data `into` cluster.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement
cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1','127.0.0.2'])
session=cluster.connect('luan')
count = 1
while(count < 500000):
 a=count
 b='luan'
 c='2016-01-01 01:01:01'
 query = SimpleStatement(
    "INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.ONE)
 session.execute(query, (a,b,c))
 session.execute("INSERT INTO t2 (a,b) VALUES (%s,%s)", (1,a))
 count = count + 1
```

When running (* ) , **getting problem** when I stopped `node1` OR `node2` and then (* ) stopped.

> cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to complete the operation
>   against any hosts', {: Unavailable('Error
>   from server: code=1000 [Unavailable exception] message="Cannot achieve
>   consistency level ONE" info={'required_replicas': 1,
>   'alive_replicas': 0, 'consistency': 'ONE'}',)})

I read on [Cassandra Calculator](http://www.ecyrd.com/cassandracalculator/), with those configurations, it said that **Each node holds 50% of your data**. `(cluster size = 2, replication factor = 1, write level = one)`

Case: `replication_factor = 2`, (* ) OK when I stopped `node1` or `node2`

**Question** :

1/ Why `replication_factor = 1`, (* ) stopped when I stopped 1 in 2 nodes ?

2/ Why "Each node holds 50% of your data" as those configurations?

Answer (score 3):

Replication Factor 1. Assuming that the cluster is balanced. There is 1 copy of your data (1 replica) in the cluster. Since you have 2 nodes and one replica, then each node will have 1/2 of the data of half a replica each. When you shut down 1 node, you lose access to 1/2 of the data.

Replication factor 2. There are 2 replicas of the data in the cluster. 2 nodes and 2 replicas -> each node can have 1 full replica. When you shut down 1 node, the other node still has a complete replica.

Comment: Could you please share me documents related to your answer ? Thank you. My assumption likes your answer but I don't understand why it is.

Comment: Here's the [datastax introduction](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/architecture/archDataDistributeReplication.html) to Replication Factor I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I read it before. `A replication factor of 1 means that there is only one copy of each row in the cluster`, but still stuck. Supposed that RF=1, 2 node, 50% data in each node ; if RF=1, 4 node, 25% data, right ?

Comment: yes, that's correct. each node has a range of partitions (or rows). They will be equally distributed among the nodes if the cluster is "balanced". 1 replica in a 4-node cluster means 1/4 data for each node.